# MICROSOFT SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO 2008R2, new schedule, what it does and where it goes?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I just clicked sql server agent -> new schedule -> named it thisisjustatest and scheduled it to run tomorrow at 1 am.
I would like to find that schedule and delete it.
I can't find it anywhere.
The platform is MICROSOFT SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO 2008R2.
Can anyone help me locate that and delete it?
What does it do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click "Jobs" under "SQL Server Agent, and choose `Manage Schedule`

[image: **Right Click Jobs**]

[image: **Delete Schedule**]

Comment: That's it. Sadly the language was different and it took me a lot to find it. Thank you sir.